# Asterisk handling multiple simultaneous calls for IVR

Tags: telephony, ivr

Hi
I am new to asterisk. I want to build an IVR system so that approximately 10-15 users can call simultaneously and use the same dialplan..
We have PRI lines and are thinking of buying Digium TE!21 card for my software.Would it serve my needs?
Please let me know how to configure dialpan and other configuration plans for my problem.
And can I simulate it without using a hartware before buying it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes Asterisk makes a wonderful IVR platform. Especially because the IVR can be programmed in any language that can write to stdin and read from stdout.

You'll need read up on Asterisk on sites like [this](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596517342/) but in the interest of getting you going here is a teaser of a very simple menu.

```
[incoming-lines]
exten => s,1,Noop()
exten => s,n(msg),Background(Press1OrPress2)
exten => s,n,WaitExten(8)
exten => s,n,Hangup()
exten => 1,1,Playback(YouPressed1)
exten => 1,n,Goto(msg)
exten => 2,1,Playback(YouPressed2)
exten => 2,n,Goto(msg)
exten => t,1,Playback(YouTimedOut)
exten => t,n,Goto(msg)
exten => i,1,Placback(YouMadeInvalidEntry)
exten => i,n,Goto(msg)
```

Now that is obviously very silly but gets the point across. If you want to take it a step further there are packages like phpagi that allow you to program the IVR in PHP. The way to make the dialplan invoke the AGI script is.

```
[incoming-lines]
exten => s,1,Noop()
exten => s,n,agi("http://yourapache/yourscript.php")
exten => s,n,Hangup()
```

I'll leave it up to you to read up on [phpagi](http://phpagi.sourceforge.net/) but this should get you started. Yes you can simulate it without any hardware. You'll need a computer with Asterisk on it of course, and a soft phone, with a speaker. That's all it takes to test IVR.